# What's the difference between code sniffing vs code linting?

Tags: javascript, syntax, devops

"Code sniffing" and "code linting" are two similarly named common practices which appear to have subtle differences. I currently confuse these terms in the same way I used to confuse weakly vs strongly typed with static vs dynamic typed, or parameters with arguments.

I've seen "sniffing" and "linting" either optionally implemented locally, or automatically checked and enforced during the CI/CD process.

What is code sniffing and code linting and what is the disambiguation between the two?

Comment: Just names for the same basic concept.

Comment: @epascarello articles on the interwebs seem to disagree, but I see some inconsistencies between them. We might need to pull JonSkeet into this discussion...

Comment: "*Backticks are appropriate not only for code, but software terminology (words like Angular, JavaScript, etc).*" [No, that's not true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text/254995#254995)

Comment: Some people say that "Sniffers" are more strict on code standards and "Linters" make it readable.  They both have rulesets and an engine that parses it. They overlap.